# Split elements in a list and compute hours for a given week

Tags: python, list, time, days

I have a string that represents when a EC2 instance is powered on and when it's powered off for each day of the week - please see the attached image for reference.

The string that results from the image is as follows: `,,4,15,,,4,9,,,5,10,,`

I want to split this string and compute the number of hours that the EC2 instance is in the "power on" state.

In this case, I believe it will be (15-4) + (9-4) + (10-5) = 12.

Still learning Python, so I am sure I can come up with a brute force approach to compute this. However, I am looking for pointers for an "elegant" solution where I am not using too many loops.

Please stay safe and be kind.

[image]

Comment: The result should be 21, right?

Comment: My bad, yes 21 is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will do the trick:

```
s = ",,4,15,,,4,9,,,5,10,,"

tokens = (int(t) for t in s.split(',') if t)
sum(y - x for x, y in zip(tokens, tokens))
# 21
```

`tokens` is an iterator over all the integers encoded in the string. By `zipping` it with itself we get consecutive neighboring pairs whose differences we can `sum` over. Alternatively, if you are more comfortable with lists and slices:

```
tokens = [int(t) for t in s.split(',') if t]
sum(tokens[1::2]) - sum(tokens[::2])
# 21
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me try that. Also, I forgot to mention that if the string is ,,,,,,,,,,,,, that implies that the instance is powered on 24 hours a day, so the value is 7*24 = 168

How can I update your code to account for this?

Comment: That seems to be one special case that you can use a simple `if-else` for. If there are other  edge cases, there might be a better abstraction to cover them all.

Comment: That makes sense. thanks. I will read up on Python iterators and slices.